# php : paypal recurring payments token is invalid

Tags: php, paypal

I used paypal php sdk with this :

https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php/blob/master/samples/RecurringPayments/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile.php

Express checkout is works well, but use recurring payments have problem : token is invalid.
Line 152 in the sdk, it's said

> A timestamped token, the value of which was returned in the response
>       to the first call to SetExpressCheckout. Call
>       CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile once for each billing
>       agreement included in SetExpressCheckout request and use the same
>       token for each call. Each CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile request
>       creates a single recurring payments profile.

But i don't understand how to "Call CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile once in SetExpressCheckout", there is my code:

```
public function createPayToken($returnUrl, $cancelUrl, $payModeData) {
    $itemName = $payModeData['name'];
    $order    = $payModeData['fee'];

    // $category = 'Digital';
    $category = 'Physical';

    $currencyCode = "USD";

    $paymentDetails = new PaymentDetailsType();

    $itemAmount = new BasicAmountType($currencyCode, $order);

    $itemDetails = new PaymentDetailsItemType();
    $itemDetails->Name = $itemName;
    $itemDetails->Amount = $itemAmount;
    $itemDetails->Quantity = 1;
    $itemDetails->ItemCategory = $category;

    $paymentDetails->OrderTotal = new BasicAmountType($currencyCode, $order);
    $paymentDetails->PaymentAction = 'Sale';
    $paymentDetails->PaymentDetailsItem[] = $itemDetails;

    $setECReqDetails = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetailsType();
    $setECReqDetails->PaymentDetails[] = $paymentDetails;
    $setECReqDetails->ReqConfirmShipping = 0;
    $setECReqDetails->NoShipping = 1;
    $setECReqDetails->AddressOverride = 0;
    $setECReqDetails->CancelURL = $cancelUrl;
    $setECReqDetails->ReturnURL = $returnUrl;

    $setECReqType = new SetExpressCheckoutRequestType();
    $setECReqType->SetExpressCheckoutRequestDetails = $setECReqDetails;

    $setECReq = new SetExpressCheckoutReq();
    $setECReq->SetExpressCheckoutRequest = $setECReqType;

    $paypalService = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService();


    try {
        $setECResponse = $paypalService->SetExpressCheckout($setECReq);
        exit;
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex;
        exit;
    }



    if(isset($setECResponse)) {
        if($setECResponse->Ack =='Success') {
            $token = $setECResponse->Token;
            return $token;
        }
        var_dump($setECResponse);
        exit;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to make sure you're including the billing agreement information in your SetExpressCheckout request.  Take a look at this [sample of set of API calls to complete a recurring payments profile using Express Checkout](http://www.angelleye.com/temp/sample-set.php).

You'll notice the SEC request includes parameters for L_BILLINGTYPE0 AND L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0.  You need to make sure you include those, otherwise the token that you get back won't be valid for CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile.